# Handling :only and :except in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I'm trying to write a method that takes `:only` and `:except` as an options hash and do some work based on those values. Quickly my code is bloated.

I can't find how Rails handles those options in let's say controller before filters?

Both `only` and `except` can be a symbol or an array eg. `:only => :show` or `:only => [:show, :destroy]`

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `_normalize_callback_options` method in [abstract_controller/callbacks.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L33) (this is rails 3).

Basically what it does is create a string containing code for conditions you wanna impose. After that you'll just need to eval this code, like

```
str = "foo == :bar || foo == :baz"
if eval(str)
  # you'd better do somethin
end
```